# Why doesn't my API call trigger with postman? MVC1005 warning

Tags: c#, rest, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api, postman

I am trying a make an API call; I start Visual Studio and enter this in postman:

```
http://localhost:51266/api/country
```

and I put a breakpoint on the method, but nothing happens. And I get an 404 not found.

This is the controller:

```
[Route("api/[controller]")]
[ApiController]
public class CountryController : Controller
{
    private ICountryRepository countryRepository;

    public CountryController(ICountryRepository repository)
    {
        this.countryRepository = repository;
    }

    [HttpGet]
    public IActionResult GetCountries()
    {
        var countries = countryRepository.GetCountries().ToList();

        return Ok(countries);
    }
}
```

What am I doing wrong here?

And I have this in the `Startup`:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddMvc();

    var connectionString = Configuration["connectionStrings:bookDbConnectionString"];
    services.AddDbContext<BookDbContext>(c => c.UseSqlServer(connectionString));

    services.AddScoped<ICountryRepository, CountryRepository>();
}
```

I have it now like this:

```
[ApiController]
public class CountryController : Controller
{
    private ICountryRepository countryRepository;

    public CountryController(ICountryRepository repository)
    {
        this.countryRepository = repository;
    }

    [HttpGet]
    [Route("api/[controller]")]
    public IActionResult GetCountries()
    {
        var countries = countryRepository.GetCountries().ToList();

        return Ok(countries);
    }
}
```

and my startup class:

```
public class Startup
{
    public static IConfiguration Configuration { get; set; }

    public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
    {
        Configuration = configuration;
    }

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
    // For more information on how to configure your application, visit https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=398940
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddMvc();

        var connectionString = Configuration["connectionStrings:bookDbConnectionString"];
        services.AddDbContext<BookDbContext>(c => c.UseSqlServer(connectionString));

        services.AddScoped<ICountryRepository, CountryRepository>();
    }

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env, BookDbContext context)
    {
        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
        }

        app.UseRouting();
    }
}
```

If I do this:

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env, BookDbContext context)
{
        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
        }

        //app.UseRouting();

        app.UseMvc();
}
```

I get this warning:

> Warning MVC1005
> Using 'UseMvc' to configure MVC is not supported while using Endpoint Routing. To continue using 'UseMvc', please set 'MvcOptions.EnableEndpointRouting = false' inside 'ConfigureServices'.  WebApplication2 D:\Mijn Documents\VisualStudio_2019\WebApplication2\WebApplication2\Startup.cs

Comment: Do you have `app.UseMvc()` in `Configure`?

Comment: At the risk of sounding extremely silly, are you running the code? You mentioned you only start Visual Studio.

Comment: ? Yes ofcourse f5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution was this:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services) {           
    services.AddMvc();
    services.AddControllers(); //added this

    var connectionString = Configuration["connectionStrings:bookDbConnectionString"];

    services.AddDbContext<BookDbContext>(c => c.UseSqlServer(connectionString));
    services.AddScoped<ICountryRepository, CountryRepository>();
}
```

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env, BookDbContext context) {

    if (env.IsDevelopment()) {
        app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
    }
  
    app.UseRouting(); //uncommented 
    app.UseAuthorization(); //added this
    app.UseEndpoints(endpoints => { //added this
        endpoints.MapControllers();
    });

    //removed the app.UseMvc(); line
}
```

Comment: Please add a sentence or two explaining what you did. Just posting code is terrible. I literally had to compare this to your original code side by side to figure out what changed, just to find out this is not helping in my situation.

Answer (score 0):

the problem is the route, it has to go on the action

```
[HttpGet]
[Route("api/[controller]")]
public IActionResult GetCountries()
```

alternatively you can keep the route on controller and just add an empty one to the action:

```
[Route("")]
```

Comment: I Updated the post

Answer (score 0):

Couple different ways to achieve this

```
[Route("api/country")]
[ApiController]
public class CountryController : Controller
{

    private ICountryRepository countryRepository;

    public CountryController(ICountryRepository repository)
    {
        this.countryRepository = repository;
    }

    [HttpGet]
    public IActionResult GetCountries()
    {

        var countries = countryRepository.GetCountries().ToList();

        return Ok(countries);

    }
 }
```

or

```
[Route("api/[controller]")]
[ApiController]
public class CountryController : Controller
{

    private ICountryRepository countryRepository;

    public CountryController(ICountryRepository repository)
    {
        this.countryRepository = repository;
    }

    [HttpGet("")]
    public IActionResult GetCountries()
    {

        var countries = countryRepository.GetCountries().ToList();

        return Ok(countries);

    }
 }
```

I like this one the best though, I think its the most intuitive

```
[Route("api")]
[ApiController]
public class CountryController : Controller
{

    private ICountryRepository countryRepository;

    public CountryController(ICountryRepository repository)
    {
        this.countryRepository = repository;
    }

    [HttpGet("country")]
    public IActionResult GetCountries()
    {

        var countries = countryRepository.GetCountries().ToList();

        return Ok(countries);

    }
 }
```

If none of these work, its because you didn't call `app.UseMVc` in your `Configure` method in `Startup.cs`

Comment: thank you I tried your last suggestion with: http://localhost:51266/api/country still nothing

Comment: The `Configure` method in your startup that you posted is missing `app.UseMvc()`. Add that.

Comment: Are you using .NET Core?

Comment: Yes, I found the solution. I Am using .net Core 3. So the latest version.